# strcmp() return different values for same string comparisons

Tags: string-comparison, strcmp, manpage, string.h

```
char s1[] = "0";
char s2[] = "9";
printf("%d\n", strcmp(s1, s2));   // Prints -9
printf("%d\n", strcmp("0", "9")); // Prints -1
```

Why do strcmp returns different values when it receives the same parameters ?

Those values are still legal since strcmp's man page says that the return value of strcmp can be less, greater or equal than 0, but I don't understand why they are different in this example.

Comment: http://ideone.com/S3dYMQ if anyone wants to play ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are using GCC when compiling this, I tried it on 4.8.4. The trick here is that GCC understands the semantics of certain standard library functions (`strcmp` being one of them). In your case, the compiler will completely eliminate the second `strcmp` call, because it knows that the result of `strcmp`given string constants `"0"` and `"9"` will be negative, and a standard compatible value (-1) will be used instead of doing the call. It cannot do the same with the first call, because `s1` and `s2` might have been changed in memory (imagine an interrupt, or multiple threads, etc.).

You can do an experiment to validate this. Add the `const` qualifier to the arrays to let GCC know that they cannot be changed:

```
const char s1[] = "0";
const char s2[] = "9";
printf("%d\n", strcmp(s1, s2));   // Now this will print -1 as well
printf("%d\n", strcmp("0", "9")); // Prints -1
```

You can also look at the assembler output form the compiler (use the `-S` flag).

The best way to check however is to use `-fno-builtin`, which disables this optimization. With this option, your original code will print -9 in both cases

Comment: I think the "cannot" part is wrong and it is really "happened not to with the given optimization settings".

Answer (score 4):

The difference is due to the implementation of strcmp.  As long as it conforms to the (<0, 0, >0), it shouldn't matter to the developer.  You cannot rely on anything else.  For all you know, the source code could be determining it should be negative, and randomly generating a negative number to throw you off.